# Maximo Anywhere 7.6.1: platform-artifacts folder is missing from the file structure

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am working on Maximo Anywhere 7.6.1.

I get an error trying to clone an app because the script is trying to copy the platform-artifact folder, which is actually not even there under the file structure `D:\eclipse\MaximoAnywhere761\MaximoAnywhere\apps\WorkExecution.`

Has anyone seen this? For what it is worth, I also removed the "platform-artifacts" Resource Filer as suggested by Scott Dickerson from another post.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my workspace. I've just deleted the workspace and imported the whole project again. That solved it. Never found the root cause.